# Find position of first (from the right) numeric character in a text string

Tags: regex, string, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have these strings:

```
fghs13412asdf
dfs234245gk
```

and want to return the position of the last numeric character, like so:

```
5
3
```

Perhaps there is something different in LibreOffice than Excel, where I'm seeing all the examples. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joZa6-cJYIc)'s one that should be straightforward, and is returning an error.

Comment: nope, different. I won't edit the difference as it asks, because the difference is self-explanatory, and questions and answers are best left as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the position of the **first** numeric character (as in the heading) or of the **last** one (as in the body of your question)?

1. If it's the **first** one, a simple SEARCH() function using regular expressions should to the trick, e.g. `=SEARCH("([:digit:])";A1)`.
2. If it's the **last** one, counted from the **start** of the string, you can use a different regex (adapted from [an answer in the OpenOffice forums by gerard24](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=74250)): `=SEARCH("[0-9][^[0-9]]+$";A1)`.
3. If you need the position of the **last** numeric character, counted from the **end** of the string, just subtract the value calculated in step 2 from the LEN() of the entire string: `=LEN(A1)-(SEARCH("[0-9][^[0-9]]+$";A1))`.

You'll get a #VALUE! error if there's no numeric character, or if the last character of the input string is numeric. Note that whitespace in the string will be ignored:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer. That was the issue I was having all along - the last character was numeric. Thanks